# Using ParSec integer function to give a Int?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I need to get an Int type from the integer function with Parsec.  My code at the moment is

```
aTerm =  parens aExpression
     <|> liftM GetV identifier
     <|> liftM N integer
```

Where the type of N is

```
N    :: Num a => a -> Expr a
```

The error I am getting is

```
Shane.hs:227:18:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Integer'
    Expected type: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT String u0 Identity Int
      Actual type: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT String u0 Identity Integer
    In the second argument of `liftM', namely `integer'
    In the second argument of `(<|>)', namely `liftM N integer'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Is it possible to extract an Int type here?  Using fromInteger some way?  Changing from Int to Integer isn't an option.

Comment: Depending on your use case, it might be necessary to check whether the parsed `Integer` is in the `Int` range, and if not let the parse fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
aTerm =  parens aExpression
     <|> liftM GetV identifier
     <|> liftM (N . fromInteger) integer
```